# Account Hierarchy value assignments when some child values need to take precedence over others

Tags: account, recursion, child-to-parent, hierarchy

We use a 4 level account hierarchy in our org that basically looks like this

```
                  Global 
        National          National
    Metro     Metro     Metro    Metro
  Unit Unit Unit Unit Unit Unit Unit Unit
```

"Unit" level relates to the billing accounts for our customers, where all the data that we need originates, but we want to roll up certain data for each level. We are utilizing the concept of "ultimate parent" aka each level has a lookup field to the global account. This can get us almost everything we need.

But we also need to calculate values for each level in certain instances, for example we track basically "lifecycle status" - unit accounts can either be prospective member, current member, or past member. And then we need each Metro and Nation to reflect the correct value based on all of the children, but we also need to make sure "Current Member" takes precedence IE if there are 2 unit accounts under a metro and one changes to "Past Member", if the other unit is still current member, we shouldn't update the metro account, and so on and so forth up the hierarchy.

We've almost solved this in 2 ways, but neither of them take into account (no pun intended) which data needs to take precedence and they are both unreliable. We written some recursive methods which dont hit SOQL limits but are very fragile with CPU time, and we've also written queries in loops in a batch job that does run with size 10, but again still doesn't solve the precedence problem, both because we haven't written the logic and we're not controlling the order in which the accounts are evaluated

Is there an approach that we're missing? Some other thoughts I had were to separate the logic for each hierarchy level into separate batches, or use a separate job to stamp helper values on each account, and then I just kind of have to hard-code a little bit that "current member" shouldn't be overwritten unless everything below it is no longer a current member".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we spoke last night on Discord. I've prepared a "simple" version of the solution, below. I know you said that you had done some work since posting your excerpt here, particularly on how the DML was achieved, but I'm assuming that kind of change would be easy to port over to the below.

The principal difference? The excerpt you posted wasn't waiting for the initial iteration through the objects in scope to *also* act on each of the maps, with the implication being that for even trivial scope sizes, an exponential increase in CPU time accompanied each iteration. I've moved the map work *out* of the initial scope iteration.

I also took the time to properly annotate the visibility on some variables, as well as standardizing how your "magic" Account `Lifecycle_Status__c` values were being referenced (by making constants for them). It's considered a best practice to do both of these things (the removal of "magic" strings in favor of constants and the explicit use of visibility keywords) so that the code is easier to read, easier to refactor, and has less implicit behavior.

Hope this helps!

```
global class batch_UpdateCurrentLifeCycleStatus implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
  private static final String CURRENT_MEMBER = 'Current Member';
  private static final String NOTICE_GIVEN = 'Notice Given';
  private static final String PAST_MEMBER = 'Past Member';

  private final Map<Id, Set<String>> metroIdToChildrenStatuses = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();
  private final Map<Id, Set<String>> nationalIdToChildrenStatuses = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();
  private final Map<Id, Set<String>> globalIdToChildrenStatuses = new Map<Id, Set<String>>();

  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
      [
        SELECT
          Id,
          ParentId,
          Parent.ParentId,
          Parent.Parent.ParentId,
          Grandparent_Account__c,
          Max_Date_of_Office_Move_Out_Today__c,
          Max_Date_of_Office_Move_Out__c,
          MRR_Helper__c,
          Lifecycle_Status__c
        FROM Account
        WHERE
          Level__c = 'Unit'
          AND Grandparent_Account__c != NULL
          AND Lifecycle_Status__c != 'Prospective Customer'
          AND ParentId != NULL
          AND Parent.ParentId != NULL
          AND Parent.Parent.ParentId != NULL
      ]
    );
  }

  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {
    Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>();

    for (Account currentAccount : scope) {
      accountMap.put(currentAccount.Id, currentAccount);

      if (currentAccount.MRR_Helper__c == 1) {
        currentAccount.Lifecycle_Status__c = CURRENT_MEMBER;
      } else if (currentAccount.MRR_Helper__c == 0 && currentAccount.Max_Date_of_Office_Move_Out_Today__c == false) {
        currentAccount.Lifecycle_Status__c = NOTICE_GIVEN;
      } else if (currentAccount.MRR_Helper__c == 0 && currentAccount.Max_Date_of_Office_Move_Out_Today__c == true) {
        currentAccount.Lifecycle_Status__c = PAST_MEMBER;
      } else {
        accountMap.remove(currentAccount.Id);
      }

      this.fillLifecycleMap(this.metroIdToChildrenStatuses, currentAccount, currentAccount.ParentId);
      this.fillLifecycleMap(this.nationalIdToChildrenStatuses, currentAccount, currentAccount.Parent.ParentId);
      this.fillLifecycleMap(this.globalIdToChildrenStatuses, currentAccount, currentAccount.Parent.Parent.ParentId);
      // end the for loop here - act on the maps AFTER
    }

    this.populateAccountsToUpdate(accountMap, this.metroIdToChildrenStatuses);
    this.populateAccountsToUpdate(accountMap, this.nationalIdToChildrenStatuses);
    this.populateAccountsToUpdate(accountMap, this.globalIdToChildrenStatuses);

    Database.update(accountMap.values());
  }

  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
  }

  private void fillLifecycleMap(Map<Id, Set<String>> lifecycleMap, Account currentAccount, Id accountKey) {
    if (lifecycleMap.containsKey(accountKey)) {
      lifecycleMap.get(accountKey).add(currentAccount.Lifecycle_Status__c);
    } else {
      lifecycleMap.put(accountKey, new Set<String>{ currentAccount.Lifecycle_Status__c });
    }
  }

  private void populateAccountsToUpdate(Map<Id, Account> accountMap, Map<Id, Set<String>> lifecycleMap) {
    for (Id lifecycleKey : lifecycleMap.keyset()) {
      Account accountToUpdate = new Account(Id = lifecycleKey);
      Set<String> lifecycleStatuses = lifecycleMap.get(lifecycleKey);
      if (lifecycleStatuses.contains(CURRENT_MEMBER)) {
        accountToUpdate.Lifecycle_Status__c = CURRENT_MEMBER;
      } else if (lifecycleStatuses.contains(NOTICE_GIVEN)) {
        accountToUpdate.Lifecycle_Status__c = NOTICE_GIVEN;
      } else if (lifecycleStatuses.contains(PAST_MEMBER)) {
        accountToUpdate.Lifecycle_Status__c = PAST_MEMBER;
      }

      accountMap.put(accountToUpdate.Id, accountToUpdate);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: very cool, thanks James! good nudge about the constants, I knew I should have done that but lost focus on it haha.

Totally makes sense to do the work on the Maps outside of the scoped records loop, feels dumb that I missed that!

I actually took your suggestion from discord, to sort the queryLocator by the top parent, and I moved the batch to be stateless, and I think for now it is close enough but i dont have a great way of validating when it's incorrect, so I will definitely give this a shot again, makes perfect sense!

Comment: I'm close but the same DML optimization isn't working - without it, the accountMap grows each batch until I hit the 10k row limit. Before I was checking an "old Set size" with local map before i put the new parent accounts from the scope into the stateful maps, and if the new Set size is the same, don't add to the accountMap. Theoretically each DML operation should be approx 800 records. any thoughts? I'm populating the "old set size map" in the scope loop and then I added it as an param for the populateAccountsToUpdate method to be able to compare.

Comment: We closed the loop on Discord about how to use a recursive queueable to update any records past the `Limits.getLimitDMLRows()` amount

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I went with for now at least - caveat that I think this only works if the hierarchies are all the same depth, ours are, so it felt like a reasonable trade-off since it does the job that recursion and queries in loop would do without flirting with governance/needing a small batch size.

Other caveat is since we may have Unit accounts across batches, this is stateful, so accounts might be updated within the execute more than once, but this also felt like a reasonable tradeoff. (but feel free to yell at me!!)

```
global class batch_UpdateCurrentLifeCycleStatus implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful{ 

Map<Id, List<String>> metroIdToChildrenStatuses = new Map<Id, List<String>>();
Map<Id, List<String>> nationalIdToChildrenStatuses = new Map<Id, List<String>>();
Map<Id, List<String>> globalIdToChildrenStatuses = new Map<Id, List<String>>();


global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    
    return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id
    , ParentId
    , Parent.ParentId
    , Parent.Parent.ParentId
    , Grandparent_Account__c
    , Max_Date_of_Office_Move_Out_Today__c
    , Max_Date_of_Office_Move_Out__c
    , MRR_Helper__c
    , Lifecycle_Status__c
    FROM Account 
    WHERE Level__c = 'Unit'
    AND Grandparent_Account__c != null AND Lifecycle_Status__c != 'Prospective Customer'
    AND ParentId != null AND Parent.ParentId != null AND Parent.Parent.ParentId != null]);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Account> scope) {

    Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>();

    for(Account currentaccount : scope) {
        System.debug(currentaccount);

        if (currentaccount.MRR_Helper__c == 1){
            currentaccount.Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Current Member';
        }

        else if (currentaccount.MRR_Helper__c == 0 && currentaccount.Max_Date_of_Office_Move_Out_Today__c == false) {
            currentaccount.Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Notice Given';   
        }

        else if (currentaccount.MRR_Helper__c == 0 && currentaccount.Max_Date_of_Office_Move_Out_Today__c == true) {
            currentaccount.Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Past Member';    
        }

        accountMap.put(currentaccount.Id, currentaccount);

        if(metroIdToChildrenStatuses.containsKey(currentaccount.ParentId)) {
            metroIdToChildrenStatuses.get(currentaccount.ParentId).add(currentaccount.Lifecycle_Status__c);
        } else {
            metroIdToChildrenStatuses.put(currentaccount.ParentId, new List<String>{currentaccount.Lifecycle_Status__c});
        }

        if(nationalIdToChildrenStatuses.containsKey(currentaccount.Parent.ParentId)) {
            nationalIdToChildrenStatuses.get(currentaccount.Parent.ParentId).add(currentaccount.Lifecycle_Status__c);
        } else {
            nationalIdToChildrenStatuses.put(currentaccount.Parent.ParentId, new List<String>{currentaccount.Lifecycle_Status__c});
        }

        if(globalIdToChildrenStatuses.containsKey(currentaccount.Parent.Parent.ParentId)) {
            globalIdToChildrenStatuses.get(currentaccount.Parent.Parent.ParentId).add(currentaccount.Lifecycle_Status__c);
        } else {
            globalIdToChildrenStatuses.put(currentaccount.Parent.Parent.ParentId, new List<String>{currentaccount.Lifecycle_Status__c});
        }

        for(Id metroId : metroIdToChildrenStatuses.keyset()) {
            if(metroIdToChildrenStatuses.get(metroId).contains('Current Member')) {
                accountMap.put(metroId, new Account(Id = metroId, Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Current Member'));
            }

            else if(metroIdToChildrenStatuses.get(metroId).contains('Notice Given')) {
                accountMap.put(metroId, new Account(Id = metroId, Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Notice Given'));
            }

            else if(metroIdToChildrenStatuses.get(metroId).contains('Past Member')) {
                accountMap.put(metroId, new Account(Id = metroId, Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Past Member'));
            }
        }

        for(Id natId : nationalIdToChildrenStatuses.keyset()) {
            if(nationalIdToChildrenStatuses.get(natId).contains('Current Member')) {
                accountMap.put(natId, new Account(Id = natId, Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Current Member'));
            }

            else if(nationalIdToChildrenStatuses.get(natId).contains('Notice Given')) {
                accountMap.put(natId, new Account(Id = natId, Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Notice Given'));
            }

            else if(nationalIdToChildrenStatuses.get(natId).contains('Past Member')) {
                accountMap.put(natId, new Account(Id = natId, Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Past Member'));
            }
        }

        for(Id globalId : globalIdToChildrenStatuses.keyset()) {
            if(globalIdToChildrenStatuses.get(globalId).contains('Current Member')) {
                accountMap.put(globalId, new Account(Id = globalId, Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Current Member'));
            }

            else if(globalIdToChildrenStatuses.get(globalId).contains('Notice Given')) {
                accountMap.put(globalId, new Account(Id = globalId, Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Notice Given'));
            }

            else if(globalIdToChildrenStatuses.get(globalId).contains('Past Member')) {
                accountMap.put(globalId, new Account(Id = globalId, Lifecycle_Status__c = 'Past Member'));
            }
        }
    }

    Database.update(accountMap.values());
}



global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
}
```